# How to convert the Title field on Image type to multi-line text box

Tags: 7

I have a Basic Page content type with a Gallery field that lets the user upload images to that page.

- when I active the Title field for the user to input a title, it shows as a single text box.

But is there a way to convert this to a multi-line text box?

Answer (score 0):

- Using the [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module, you can add fields to images, such as description or caption.

  **OR**
- Alternatively, you could use the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to create a 'Gallery image' field type, which has the extra fields that you need.